# How to arrange table data in parent child format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to arrange the table in a parent - child structure.

How to query this table?

```
txnno   Name        type    isHeadr headr
------------------------------------------
1000    BEFORE      JO      Y   
1001    WHILE       JO      Y   
1002    data aaa    JO      N       1000
1003    bbbbdfds    JO      N       1000
1004    ccccccc     JO      N       1000
1012    aaa111      JO      N       1001
1015    bbb222      JO      N       1001
1016    ccc333      JO      N       1001
```

to get this result in my SQL Server:

```
txnno   Name        type    isHeadr headr
-----------------------------------------
1000    BEFORE      JO      Y       
1002    data aaa    JO      N       1000
1003    bbbbdfds    JO      N       1000
1004    ccccccc     JO      N       1000
1001    WHILE       JO      Y
1012    aaa111      JO      N       1001
1015    bbb222      JO      N       1001
1016    ccc333      JO      N       1001
```

Comment: Can you please check this link and improve your question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ISNULL(headr,txnno) ASC, isHeadr DESC, txnno
```

Output:

```
txnno   Name        type    isHeadr headr
1000    BEFORE      JO      Y       NULL
1002    data aaa    JO      N       1000
1003    bbbbdfds    JO      N       1000
1004    ccccccc     JO      N       1000
1001    WHILE       JO      Y       NULL
1012    aaa111      JO      N       1001
1015    bbb222      JO      N       1001
1016    ccc333      JO      N       1001
```

If you have `0` instead of `NULL` use [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ISNULL(NULLIF(headr,0),txnno) ASC, isHeadr DESC, txnno
```

Comment: This does assume that parents will have lower `txnno` values than their children, which is what the OPs sample data seems to show but isn't a certainty.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever add `, isHeadr DESC` to handle this situations.